# Displaying a valueBox based on select_filter (crosstalk)

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

Within my Rmarkdown/flexdashboard code, I want to generate a valueBox displaying the sum of costs, based on a filter. I constructed this filter by using crosstalk, see the code below. However, I cannot seem to take the filter into account, and if I do, I get tons of errors.

If tried pulling the filters from different data, the sd (shareddata) and from my old showcase_df.

````
---
title: "test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
---
Column {data-width=150}
---------

```{r}
library(crosstalk)
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

showcase_df <- data.frame(c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"), c(1,5,3,2,4,1))
colnames(showcase_df) <- c("category", "costs")
shared_data <- SharedData$new(showcase_df)

filter_select("showcase_filter", "A or B?", shared_data, showcase_df$category)

valueBox(sum(showcase_df$costs))
```
````

I also tried `valueBox(sum(sd$costs))` etcetera. The error messages I get are mostly "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. To sum up, I would like to construct a valueBox based on my filter

Comment: You refer to `test1` and `test2` in `showcase_df` without ever defining them.

Comment: Excuse me, I left one line out by accident. I have just fixed it., should've been category and costs respectively. Excuse me, sloppy

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/112

Comment: @rdatasculptor Ah, I see you bumped the question, very nice. I'll keep an eye on it

Comment: @Maurice, please take a look here: https://twitter.com/timelyportfolio/status/1278763232057085957?s=19 exciting new project!

Comment: @rdatasculptor Nice! Really nice, thanks for sharing :)